# Install third-party public ssh key

Tags: ssh

A customer emailed me a .pub file for ssh. How do I install it so that their user account (and only their user account) is able to log in with an ssh key?

There are other users that log in to this machine but they need to be able to provide a password - only this user should be using an ssh key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server to have:

```
Match User <username>
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Then just add the `.pub` key file to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server with:

```
cat key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Make sure to restart SSH afterwards with `sudo service ssh restart`

Comment: cat key.pub >> /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys?

Comment: @divided Yes, that is correct